# line up button - multiple lines of text then button

Tags: html, css

I have a html page with a few lines each containing text then a button. The text is of different length but I'd like css to automatically add space between each piece of text and button so the buttons line up vertically.

For example:

```
<p>Complete part one: <button id="one" type="button">One</button></p>
<p>Now fill in section two: <button id="two" type="button">Two</button></p>
```

Looks like:

[image]

Whereas I'd like it to line up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPLX9/)

Simply add in your CSS

```
button{
  float:right;
}
```

If you wish to restrict the width of the 'lines' simply do, e.g.:

```
p{
  width:400px; /* or similar to limit the width */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added an id to the buttons so it only effected the buttons not the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can add simply the button css as described in the above user. but Its better if u define another container css class

```
.Container{
    width:200px;
}
```

and put your html page inside it.something like this

```
div class = "Container">
    your code here
</div>
```

Andmake it look better like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cPLX9/2/) and In my opinion its better if you use div tab instead of paragraph to define the width.